# django hash password when create user from shell

Tags: python, django, hash

I am using [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)  to create a custom **User** model. I want to test this through django shell.

When I create a user from django shell using `MyUser.objects.create(email='some@example.com', data_of_birth=datetime.date.today(), password='somepassword')`, the password doesn't get hashed and is stored in the database as plaintext.

But if I create a user through django admin portal, it gets stored as a hash.

What do I need to do so that it gets stored as hash even through shell? Do I need to implement some function of my own?

Django version 1.7.3

Comment: staff = Staff()
            staff.username = username
            staff.set_password(password)    here staff is inherited model from USER , when user enter  password you just give to the set_password , django automaticaly converted into hasble pwd

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `User.set_password()`:

```
user = MyUser(email='some@example.com'), ...)
user.set_password('somepassword')
user.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
staff = Staff()
staff.username = username
staff.set_password(password)
staff.save()
```

here staff is inherited model from USER , when user enter  password you just give to the set_password , django automaticaly converted into hasble pwd